# Is there a similar formula in spherical and hyperbolic geometry as Euclidean Geometry?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

1. In an Euclidean plane,  we know that the area of a triangle is determined by the length of base and the height, i.e.,
   $$
   S_{\Delta}=\frac{1}{2}a.h,
   $$
   where $a$ is the length of base and the $h$ is the height. Is there a similar formula in Spherical and hyperbolic spaces?
2. In Euclidean plane, we know that the cosine law says that (suppose $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are the angles, and $a, b, c$ are the lengths opposite $a, b, c$ respectively.)
   $$
   \cos\gamma=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}.
   $$
   Then is there a analogue in spherical and hyperbolic geometry? I have noted that the First and Second Cosine law are not so clearly relevant with this formula.

Comment: Posted even on MathStackexchange, here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76084/is-there-a-similar-formula-in-spherical-and-hyperbolic-geometry-as-eucl

Comment: Is that illegal to a same question on two site?
if it is, I owe an apologize.

Comment: It’s certainly legal, but rather frowned upon, because it fragments the discussion and leads to duplication of effort. It makes sense to repost a question on the other site if you do not receive any answers, but you should wait a couple of days before doing so. In any case, you should crosslink the two questions to each other (which Giuseppe just did) so that people know.

Comment: Thanks, That is reasonable, I will do that in my following questions.

Answer (score 2):

For hyperbolic geometry, you can find the answers to your questions on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_triangle).  An interesting thing is that there is an absolute upper bound on the area of a hyperbolic triangle, even though lengths are unbounded.

For spherical geometry, you can find the area of a spherical triangle [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalTriangle.html) and corresponding trigonometric formulas [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalTrigonometry.html).

Comment: Another interesting thing is that the area of a hyperbolic triangle is determined by its three angles.

Comment: And the area of a spherical triangle likewise.

Comment: And in both cases, a countably infinite set of circle-square pairs of equal area, both of which are constructible with compass and straightedge. But no algorithm that starts with either a square or circle of unknown area and produces the matching figure. I'm just saying.

Comment: @Will.  Good point.  I guess I used *the* where I meant to use *an*.  I did not intend to imply the uniqueness of interestingness.  I have edited accordingly.  